# Difference between memory usage when importing modules

Tags: python, memory, import-module

I'd like to know whats is the difference between the memory usage when importing modules in these ways:

```
import Mod1
from Mod1 import *
from Mod1 import a,b,c
```

Mainly between the first two.

Comment: You can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372966/python-modules-when-one-imports-them-do-they-go-into-memory

Comment: I didn't understand well... So the first two examples, there isn't difference between them?

Comment: @HugoSousa The op here is asking to compare the memory usage of different import methods, the link is answering the memory usage of imports in general.

Comment: Yes, there is differences: in the first/second one you are importing everything inside the module; in the third one you are only importing `a`, `b` and `c` function. The difference between the first one and the second one is in the first it is not a module here, it's a package. Using the first import you have to do Mod1.function(), in the second import you can call the function directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first uses the least memory since it only creates a single name in the module scope.

The second uses the most (assuming `Mod1` contains more than just `a`, `b`, and `c` either explicitly or in `__all__`) since all names are recreated.

In all three cases the entire module is imported and executed, so if you're looking for large memory savings this is not what you want to optimize.